# Geo-location Google Maps API not functioning on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am trying to implement Geo-location within my application however whilst it works on desktop whenever it load the application onto the mobile it does not work. I have the following code which is taken from the google documentation:

```
    // Try HTML5 geolocation
  if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                       position.coords.longitude);



      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        map: map,
        position: pos,
        content: 'Current Location'
      });

      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
    ///Place fallback loop
  }
```

Is there any reason as to why this potentially does not function on a mobile?

Comment: I am using Google Chrome on my android device

Comment: Did you not deny geolocation?

Comment: weird.... if you connect with browser it must work, you test only in one device? it happens in others? maybe as @MrUpsidown proposes you denied it by default and now you don't see the geolocation approval modal

Comment: Ive managed to test it in the last hour on other devices and it is working fine on some but not others, it is quite strange

Answer (score 0):

Check if the device has settings of share location false in device. When a page script is requesting for location browser will ask for user permission in android device browser. May be you have clicked never share your location. Please check it by clearing the browser settings in your device.